# Matrix Vector Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

sorry if this is a dumb question.

I was wondering if a matrix vector multiplication can be thought as a linear transformation of the vector. Then how does, for example, a 3 x 2 matrix multiplied by a 2 x 1 vector work? The output would be a 3 x 1 vector and so the 2 x 1 vector has been transformed to a 3 x 1 vector (from R2 to R3)?

Comment: Yes, a matrix can be viewed a linear transformation from one vector space to another. In your example, from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$.